# Error al instalar composer en Manjaro

Tags: php, laravel, composer

no llevo mucho tiempo usando linux ( manjaro) y estoy intentando instalar composer para poder trabajar en un proyecto de la universidad. Para poner al tanto, ya tengo instalado LAMP.

Por el momento hice esto:

1) yay -S composer --noconfirm

2) composer global require "laravel/installer" y me sale este error...

> PHP Warning:  Phar::mapPhar(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/usr/bin/composer) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/srv/http/) in /usr/bin/composer on line 23 PHP Warning:  require():
>   open_basedir restriction in effect. File(composer.phar) is not within
>   the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/) in /usr/bin/composer on line 24 PHP
>   Warning:  require(phar://composer.phar/bin/composer): failed to open
>   stream: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar
>   "phar://composer.phar/bin/composer" in /usr/bin/composer on line 24
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'phar://composer.phar/bin/composer' (include_path='.:') in
>   /usr/bin/composer on line 24

Se que debo agregar algo al php.ini pero no sé como hacerlo. Agradeceria su ayuda compañeros.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@Alfabravo acá te adjunto una imagen del archivo en /bin/composer y creo que ahí es 
la linea 24

Comment: El archivo php.ini lo puedes encontrar en el directorio `/etc/php/`. Lo puedes abrir con cualquier editor de texto, pero para editarlo necesitarás acceder como superusuario. Por ejemplo para abrirlo con el editor nano `sudo nano /etc/php/php.ini`.

Comment: Entiendo pero que debo agregar o quitar en el php.ini. No entiendo lo de la terminal

Comment: Pues depende... en principio busca en el php.ini la linea que comienza con `open_basedir =` y muestra que tienes ahí. Nota también que composer está en los repositorios oficiales de manjaro, y lo más recomendable es instalarlo desde ahí, en vez de desde AUR como lo hiciste.